# Angular - Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] when using $http to get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I just started using AngularJs, I am having issue when using $http to get data and $scope.productInfos = data returns Error: [ngRepeat:dupes], below is my code:

```
$scope.processForm = function(formData) {

        $http({

          method  : 'POST',

          url: '/quote-tool/productinfoforproductids/', // using php to generate json i.e [{id:1},{id:2}]

          data: $('.js-checkedCompareForm').serialize(),

          headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)

         }).success(function(result) {

            $scope.productInfos = result;

         }).error(function(err) {

             return err; 

        });
    };
```

in the view:

```
<div class="js-productInfo" ng-repeat="productInfo in productInfos">
    {{ productInfo.id }}
</div>
```

I am not sure angular see it as a repeated dup?
I have been trying using track by $index, but still not working instead, it shows excessive repeats in the view.

Comment: to help you troubleshoot this problem, we would need to see an example of what is in `$scope.productInfos`, and what the incorrect output looks like.

Comment: Hi @Mike, could you please provide us the data that is returned from your http call?

Comment: @Mike, if you can't give the exact result, just give us example data. And check whether is there any duplicate entries are in your result as specified in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when you have duplicate keys in an ngRepeat expression.May be using `track by $index` will solve your problem.Look at this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

```
<div class="js-productInfo" ng-repeat="productInfo in productInfos track by $index">
    {{ productInfo.id }}
</div>
```

If you still get an error then please provide fiddle/plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem, its caused by the php generated json file which generate a bad json format that causes the error in the data response.

```
was: {id:1},{id:2}

 should be:  {
    "productInfos":[
      {id:1},
      {id:2}
    ]
  }
```